# Different between Superuser and superuser meta

Tags: discussion, windows-10

What is different between Super user and super user meta?

I know that I shouldn’t ask this question in this site.But I  was forced.

Comment: "Meta" in English refers to the *rules* or *nature* of the system, e.g. " Making or showing awareness of reference to oneself or to the activity." I.E., it is self-referential.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik May you explain to me simply!? Unfortunately I can’t read English very well.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Do you mean the psychology of that field(site)!?

Comment: Read these definitions and let us know what you don't understand: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meta; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta

Comment: But I don’t mean the word meta meaning.i want to know its meaning in stack Exchange,And as I said,I can’t read English unless it is simply stated

Comment: Our help centre has a page dedicated to this: ["What is meta?"](https://superuser.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help) - which every user should read & be familiar with

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
> question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

Super User Meta is for asking questions on the main site's operation, policy & administrative functions.
See the Meta help page for additional details - [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://superuser.com/help/whats-meta)

As such, this question should have been posted on Meta, not the main Super User site.
Posting meta questions on the main site tends to receive rapid downvotes & close votes & is to be avoided.

Comment: More specifically, also from our help: ["What is meta?"](https://superuser.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @Mokubai - ah, I'd forgotten that one - will drop into answer...

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, (Almost) every single site has a "meta" site, for asking questions about the site.

Sometimes, you might want to appeal or understand a closure. Other times, you might want to understand how things work.

Super User is for asking questions about the things on topic on Super User. Meta is for asking questions *about* Super User, the site.

Answer (score 0):

Besides meta sites of individual stack exchange Q&A sites, there is Meta Stack exchange which involves general meta questions about the whole Stack exchange network itself.